# greater than x and less than y php not working

Tags: php, random, if-statement

I'm trying to declare a variable depending on what the number is.

I'm trying to do "if $var is less than [amount] and greater than [amount] var = blah elseif $var is less than [amount] and greater than [amount] var = blah" etc. Here is my code:

```
$randomNumber = rand(1, $funnyPicsHigh);

if($randomNumber > 0 && $randomNumber < 2001){
$directory_to_use = 1;

}elseif($randomNumber > 2000 && $randomNumber < 4001){
$directory_to_use = 2;

}elseif($randomNumber > 4000 && $randomNumber < 6001){
$directory_to_use = 3;

}elseif($randomNumber > 6000 && $randomNumber < 8001){
$directory_to_use = 4;

}elseif($randomNumber > 8000 && $randomNumber < 10001){
$directory_to_use = 5;

}elseif($randomNumber > 10000 && $randomNumber < 12001){
$directory_to_use = 6;

}elseif($randomNumber > 10000 && $randomNumber < 12001){
$directory_to_use = 7;

}elseif($randomNumber > 12000 && $randomNumber < 14001){
$directory_to_use = 8;

}elseif($randomNumber > 14000 && $randomNumber < 16001){
$directory_to_use = 9;

}elseif($randomNumber > 16000 && $randomNumber < 18001){
$directory_to_use = 10;

}elseif($randomNumber > 18000 && $randomNumber < 20001){
$directory_to_use = 11;

}
```

I started out using if then elseif for everything, I then changed it so it is >= and <=, still didn't work, then I tried putting " " before and after my numbers which is what you see now, still didn't work.

The random number executes just fine, but it seems to pick a random directory. I'll refresh the page and it picks 5 for the directory to use. I refresh it again and it picks 1, then picks 1, then picks 3. It seems to just randomly pick a number.

What am I doing wrong?

---

FIGURED it out, thank you everyone. It was due to my logic not the code provided. Talking out loud trying to explain my problem is what helped me so thanks. If wondering what the working code is, it's here:
http://pastebin.com/en2sc3HC

Comment: Why do you need quotes around numbers??

Comment: You don't need quotes around the numbers since rand() returns an int.

Comment: I don't, if you read my post I said that I originally didn't have the quotes, but sense that didn't work I tried adding the quotes to see if maybe my ints were strings or other way around. I tried both, neither worked.

Comment: I'm confused, isn't that the expected behavior? A random number determining a directory would produce a random directory...

Comment: Isn't random behavior what you are supposed to expect given that you're picking a random number on the first line? For testing purposes, you can do `$randomNumber = 3000;` and see if your code correctly returns `$directory_to_use = 2;`

Comment: It should pick the CORRECT directory depending on what the number is. So if the number is under 2000, no matter if it is 1435 or 1896 it should pick directory 1. However it picks directory 6 some times, picks 3 other times, picks 1 other times, picks 11 others etc.

Comment: I am. I've been choosing 1435. It sometimes makes $directory_to_use = 1, other times it makes it equal 5, other times it equals 8, etc. Even though $randomNumber is ALWAYS 1435.

Comment: You can see what I mean by going to http://www.dlolpics.com/?p=1435      If you refresh the page, you'll see the direct image directory changes.

Comment: @Travis: You're obviously missing something, or we're not seeing all the code you're using. From the code given, this is not possible.

Comment: You were right animuson. I was just editing my index to show you guys what I mean by echoing the numbers and I realized my mistake. Haha thanks guy :P

Comment: @Travis: I think problem might in $funnyPicsHigh variable. Is your variable declared well? Because I have taken it's value as max 20001. Script was working well.

Comment: Yeah I forgot I only use $randomNumber if post data isn't declared. If post data is declared I use the post data variable. :s

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code can be significantly simplified

```
$directory_to_use = ceil(rand(1, $funnyPicsHigh) / 2000);
```

if that is a typo

```
}elseif($randomNumber > 10000 && $randomNumber < 12001){
$directory_to_use = 6;

}elseif($randomNumber > 10000 && $randomNumber < 12001){
$directory_to_use = 7;
```

Comment: Indeed, or use `ceil()` in stead of `floor()` and ditch the `+ 1`

Comment: @fireeyedboy     Thanks ) I was thinking about it, but OP's typo confused me (I was trying to find what is wrong with the last numbers), that is why I forgot to rewrite with ceil. I'll fix it :)

Comment: I'm sure my code can be simplified, however that specific example won't work for the application I use.

Comment: @Cheery: You're welcome. I ran into the same problem when I tested it. :)

Comment: @Travis it is not clear what do you expect when you use random numbers generator. It will generate **random** number at every call. `$randomNumber is ALWAYS 1435.` Show where do set it in your code - before random or after?.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear, but like usual, once you start thinking out loud just trying to explain it to someone you realize your error. If you are curious on what I was trying to do here it is http://pastebin.com/en2sc3HC

Comment: Thanks for that catch too, didn't see that. It was a typo

Comment: @Travis        But you do not need all these `if` statements - everything can be converted into a couple of lines. Also I do not know where you are going to use those URLs for images, but it is very insecure to insert there data directly from the user - it may lead to XSS vulnerability.

Comment: @Travis Look here http://pastebin.com/xW13C8GU

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code as-is, in a loop 100 times, with the following statements at the end:

```
echo nl2br("Number: {$randomNumber} \r\n");
echo nl2br("Directory: {$directory_to_use} \r\n");
```

And got output like this:

```
Number: 19984 
Directory: 11 

Number: 16677 
Directory: 10 

Number: 12097 
Directory: 8 

Number: 10123 
Directory: 6 

Number: 8341 
Directory: 5 

Number: 18832 
Directory: 11 

Number: 13325 
Directory: 8 

Number: 5228 
Directory: 3 

Number: 11034 
Directory: 6 

Number: 3605 
Directory: 2 

Number: 19827 
Directory: 11
```

**In short, your code is working as expected.**

Comment: PS - your code would never set `$directory_to_use` to 7 due to the the bug pointed out by Cherry

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically.

So using quotes around the number literals shouldn't be a problem. Moving on..

> The random number executes just fine...It seems to just randomly pick a number. What am I doing wrong?

**... nothing!** If it changes randomly every time you refresh the page it must be running `rand()` every time. If you'd like the directory to persist after you refresh the page, consider storing it in a session variable, checking if it's set on page load, and if so, don't re-generate it. Combining this idea with @cheery's:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    // store random directory in a session var if not set
    if (!$_SESSION['randir']) {
        $_SESSION['randir'] = ceil(rand(1, $funnyPicsHigh) / 2000);
    }
    $directory_to_use = $_SESSION['randir'];

?>
```